# Airplane mode and security?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, laptop, bluetooth, smartphone

It's for creating an idea about a scenario or because to a strange behavior I encountered.

E.g. A system is hardened, without knowing if there could be already a malware on it. And the Network mode is switched to Airplane mode.

Could Malware make use of a Wireless/bluetooth-card nonetheless on the GUI the airplanemode is switched off ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, almost all malwares have root/admin previlege, which allow them to do anything on the system.

-And the maleware(Remote Access Trojan) could be used through the wireless or bluetooth-card ?

Yes.

-Or might be there a hidden radio frequency tool ?

No software can do things exceeding the hardware capability, if a wireless card is only 2.4Ghz, then the malware cannot use 5Ghz.

-Could such traffic be discovered ?

It depends, but you should use another computer to analyze the traffic, because the malware may hide anything on a victim computer.

Comment: And the maleware(Remote Access Trojan) could be used through the wireless or bluetooth-card ? Or might be there a hidden radio frequency tool ? Could such traffic be discovered ?

Comment: Thanks, I meant with a hidden radio frequency tool a hardware tool e.g. inside an usb-port, which survives a new OS installation ? Maybe be the maleware could create a virtual wireless interface beside the normal wireless client interface ?

Comment: If the hacker have/had physical access to a machine, then no security method is effective. Of course it can survives a new OS installation.

Comment: Due I'm a very uninterested normal person, the question is who else can do it.  https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/12/inside-the-nsas-leaked-catalog-of-surveillance-magic/